# extjs file size is so big what to do

Tags: extjs, size

I am building an application in extjs, the ext-all.js size is 700kb which is very big and not acceptable by our technical architect. So what should I do ?

Should I remove extjs and build in some other UI.

or

I can do something about size ?

Comment: try the minified version of ext js file ...

Comment: what is the size of minified extjs

Comment: i posted you a link to the Minified project - download it and try it out, then you will see exactly how much you save.

Comment: but ext-all.js is already minified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should calmly but firmly explain the following to your technical architect:

1. The browser will treat the JavaScript file as a static resource and cache it after the initial download, so each visitor will only download the file once (unless they clear their browser cache, which most people don't), even if it is included on every page on the website.
2. Any modern web server supports automatic gzip compression of text documents (which includes things like JavaScript files).  Assuming this is enabled, it means that the amount of data that the client actually downloads is significantly less than 700 KB.  You can see what the actual download size is by taking your 700 KB JavaScript file and archiving it with gzip (or any equivalent utility).

Comment: i didn't understand how should i explain the second point , how should i explain ?

Comment: Here's an [article](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/compress/) on the subject.  In essence, your web server should have HTTP compression turned on.  If it does, it will compress the JavaScript file before it sends it to the client.  This means that the actual amount of data downloaded by the client will be much less than 700 KB.  It should be closer to 100-200 KB.

Comment: how to on the http compression in firefox ?

Comment: is it something we need to do on server with apache  ?

Comment: Yes, you need to enable `mod_deflate`.  This [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [Ajax Minifier](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/) on the `ext-all.js` file? It should drastically reduce its size. Not to mention that browser caching should make it a one-time download (unless you update the underlying file).